# subset sum from recursive backtracking

Tags: algorithm, combinations, subset, subset-sum

I am trying to modify the "List all combinations in a string" question, to a problem where we need to print all sets that have a given 'sum'. Here is my initial Code, but I am not sure how I can save the list of sets in the code:

```
/**
 * method to return  all sets with a given sum.
 **/
public static List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static void countSubsetSum3(int arr[], int k, int sum) {
    if(sum == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if(sum != 0 && k == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if(sum < arr[k - 1]) {
        countSubsetSum3(arr, k-1, sum);
    }
    countSubsetSum3(arr, k-1, sum - arr[k-1]);
    countSubsetSum3(arr, k-1, sum);
}
```

How can we modify this code to make it print all possible sets that have the sum 'sum'. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return from your function when `string`'s length is `0`. Right now you're just printing your `prefix` and then the line:

```
subset(prefix + string.charAt(0), string.substring(1));
```

is executed, which raises `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you're calling `.substring(1)` on an empty  string.

Comment: Cannot believe I overlooked it. Thank you!

Comment: It should be relatively easy to spot. Do you use any debugger?

Comment: I don't. Any recommendations?

Comment: Most of the popular IDE's, for example [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) have a built-in debugger. It is a very useful tool, which allows you to run your program step by step and inspect the variables during runtime.

Comment: Thanks, Welter. I use eclipse, and so, I just got started using JUnit. FYI: I just modified the question slightly to try to see how I can modify the original code to make it solve the problem: GIven a set, return all sub sets that have a given 'sum'. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: I think it's a much better idea to start a new question instead of modifying an existing one, because now my accepted answer does not answer your question. About the code: generally you have to memorize somehow which array elements you took and which you didn't, so that you will be able to print them when the sum is right. And some technical advice: you don't have to check is `sum != 0` in the second `if` because the first `if` ensures it. And the recursive calls: you sometimes call `countSubsetSum3(arr, k-1, sum)` twice, which makes no sense. And you protect the wrong call with an `if`.